# What exactly does volley.VolleyError.NetworkError mean in android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am a bit confused about volley NetworkError, and about the difference between NetworkError and NoConnectionError. The doc says this about NetworkError -

> Indicates that there was a network error when performing a Volley
>   request.

What do they mean by "network error"? When is NoConnectionError raised and when is NetworkError raised?

Comment: Google searches do not provide sufficient information. The documentation is severely lacking. I don't see why this was voted down. It's a good and valid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No connection Error - you doesn't have a data connection and wi-fi Connection

Network Error - you may login with some wi-fi  which is under firewall means you are connected but not able to transfer data. you are allowed to transfer only even after login manually with the firewall.

Before login to firewall the network error is displayed

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best explanation I've seen so far! I would like to add `NoConnectionError` is also thrown when you try to access a non existing url.